# Protractor - iterate through all elements by count() function doesn't work for me

Tags: javascript, loops, count, protractor, automated-tests

I want to iterate through elements by:

```
let newsCards = element.all(by.css('.design-article--without-image.design-article.design-tile'));

  for(let card = 0; card <= newsCards.count(); card++) {}
```

and it doesn't work for me.

It doesn't call any error, my test passes but don't do what it should. I solve it by simple number iteration, but I would be happy to know why there is an issue to iterate with count().

Can somebody help me with this?

Comment: What it should do? "one mistake" (depending on your scenario) is that you start the loop from 0 but you go up until the total number of elements, instead of n - 1. So `card <= newsCards.count()` should actually be `card < newsCards.count()`

Answer (score 0):

`newsCards.count()` is a Promise. You need to resolve it first to get a number eventually. Normally you do it this way using `await` keyword

```
let newsCards = element.all(by.css('.design-article--without-image.design-article.design-tile'));

let count = await newsCards.count()
for(let card = 0; card < count; card++) {}
```

Keep in mind, that what was said in comments is also right and you should be using `<` instead of `<=`

Comment: sure @vvokalkov if worked, please accept and upvote